# pthread_mutex_t  VS  @synchronized block?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cocoa, mutex, synchronized

```
static pthread_mutex_t gLock; //global 

pthread_mutex_init(&gLock,NULL); //in init

pthread_mutex_lock(&gLock);
for(int i=0;i<[message count];i++)
CFSetAddValue(mSet, [message objectAtIndex:i]);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&gLock);
```

My cocoa application is going in not responding mode with pthread_mutex_t.

```
@synchronized(mSet)
{
for(int i=0;i<[message count];i++)
    CFSetAddValue(mSet, [message objectAtIndex:i]);
}
```

My application is working fine with synchronized block.

Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're comparing a global lock (one lock for all instances) to an object level recursive lock (one lock per instance, which may be acquired multiple times from the same thread). These are not generally interchangeable -- they operate and protect very different from each other.

The good news is, you can use `pthread_mutex_t` as a recursive lock which is unique to each instance in order to achieve the same degree of protection as `@synchronized`. Using `pthread_mutex_t` also makes lock acquisitions much, much faster.

To achieve the same effect as `@synchronized` using a pthread mutex, declare `pthread_mutex_t gLock` as an instance variable, then initialize it as a recursive mutex in `-init`. Finally, destroy the mutex in `-dealloc`.

Of course, sub- and base- classes may need access to this lock if they relied on the semantics of `@synchronized` to do the right thing through the object hierarchy.

`@synchronized` is veeeeeeery slow in comparison to a recursive pthread mutex (last I checked).

Comment: In .h file  pthread_mutexattr_t    attr;
 pthread_mutex_t         mutex;

in init 
  pthread_mutexattr_settype(&attr, PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE);
  pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, &attr);
in dealloc
pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);   

in my function
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    CFSetRemoveAllValues(mySet);
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

is this fine?

Comment: @ParagBafna a) the mutex attr may be `static`, and used for every mutex you create - or non-static and used only in `-init` b) the mutex attr need not be an ivar c) you should verify your result codes d) you may also prefer `pthread_mutex_trylock` in some cases. e) you should initialize the structs using the initializers. other than that, looks good! prepare for fast locking =)

Comment: the result codes are useful mostly to detect locking and threading errors.

Comment: pthread_mutex_lock and pthread_mutex_unlock returns errorcode 22

Comment: I forgot to write pthread_mutexattr_init(&attr); in init , now its working fine. I am using same CFMutableSet in other classes also, what should i do?

Comment: in PthreadMutexClass

-(pthread_mutex_t *)PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE_LOCK
{
 return &mutex;
}


in other class

pthread_mutex_lock([mPthreadMutexClassObject PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE_LOCK]);

is this fine?

Comment: @ParagBafna for basic support, you could: a) create a base class with this locking support and adopt `NSLocking` (`e.g. @interface MONLockableObject : NSObject < NSLocking >`) b) create a subclass (`e.g. @interface MONLockableObject : MONLockableMutableSet`) which has a set as an ivar/property. -- for frequent usage, subclassing `NSMutableSet` may be worth consideration. i would not expose the `pthread_mutex_t` -- if locking needs to be public, just adopt `@protocol NSLocking`.

Answer (score 0):

Justin is right; there is also another detail, however, which is exception handling. From 
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html comes this tip:

> As a precautionary measure, the @synchronized block implicitly adds an exception handler to the protected code. This handler automatically releases the mutex in the event that an exception is thrown. This means that in order to use the @synchronized directive, you must also enable Objective-C exception handling in your code. If you do not want the additional overhead caused by the implicit exception handler, you should consider using the lock classes.

If `[message count]` can raise exceptions that could jump over your unlock code and wedge you up.

Comment: …if you can recover. most cocoa exceptions are not recoverable (at least, if you want predictable execution thereafter). the common case for a recoverable exception would be c++ (predictable recovery).